# Python code returns "None"

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def average(numbers):
    total = float(sum(numbers))
    total /= len(numbers)
    return
```

Error: Oops, try again.

`average([3, 0])` returned `None` instead of `1.5` as expected.

What is wrong pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any value.

Try this instead:

```
def average(numbers): 
    total = float(sum(numbers)) 
    total /= len(numbers) 
    return total
```

Comment: Hi @costinv if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.